# Did we ever actually find out Sarah's full real name?

Tags: chuck

Throughout the series, we find that Sarah doesn't like discussing her past. This arc really comes into play during the episode where she meets up with an old college friend in the Orange Orange and her name during college is revealed to have been Jennifer Burton.

Sometime later, Daniel Shaw starts calling Sarah by the name "Sam", stating this to be her real name, and judging by the reaction he consistently gets from Sarah when he calls her this, this is probably her actual real name. However, her surname doesn't ever seem to get mentioned.

Did we ever actually find out Sarah's full real name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We never quite find out.  She first revealed that her actual middle name is Lisa in "Chuck versus the Wookiee" (Season 1, Episode 4).  In "Chuck versus the Fake Name" (Season 3, Episode 8), she tells Agent Shaw that her real first name is Sam (presumably short for Samantha).  But the only suggestion we have for a last name is that her father used the alias "Jack Burton" and that she attended high school as "Jenny Burton" ("Chuck versus the Cougars", Season 2, Episode 4).  So she may have been born Samantha Lisa Burton, but it seems more likely that she and her father simply had pseudonyms that plausibly matched rather than using their real last name.